# Voronoi map: Unable to find data that I just associated with an object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a Voronoi map so that I can create labels for a big set of circles. I am following the example from Mike Bostock [step by step](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-voronoi-labels), but I'm running into an error and I'm not sure why.

I initialize my voronoi cells and then try to create paths for each of the polygons.

```
      const cells = d3.voronoi()
        .extent([[0, 0], [600, 700]])
        .polygons(circle_locations)

      const cell = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "voronoiWrapper")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(cells)
        .enter()

        cell.append("path")
          .attr("stroke", "#orange")
          .attr("d", d => `M${d.join("L")}Z`);
```

It gives me the error that `d` is undefined. But that confuses me since I joined cells to the object `cell` right above. This is literally copy paste what the example has, but it's not quite working.

This is a demo with my [data](https://bl.ocks.org/wdtglrn/ce485e3d59403c8c58fd2a49c9ff4de2/4f455302d3658223362b30419ac4886596a85958). There's a bunch of random stuff not related to this, but this snippet is at the bottom of `main.js` if you wanna look.

Comment: The js error your demo shows is that `radius` is an undefined variable.

Comment: I was deleting stuff to make the example shorter and accidentally deleted `radius`. I fixed it, but the error is still going on. o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current extent's `x1` and `y1` values ...

```
const cells = d3.voronoi()
    .extent([[0, 0], [600, 700]])
    //these------------^----^
```

... are too low. Because of that, you have empty arrays in your `cells` data array.

Increase that boundary according to the position of your circles and you won't have a undefined datum anymore. Alternatively, just filter the data array (`cells`) for valid values.

Comment: I don't want to make the extent too large. I'm going to apply `filter` to the `cells` data in the `cell` variable. Either way- thank you, that solved it. It's a lot of fun to see the voroni.